# updating existing javascript variables

Tags: javascript

This may or maynot be a simple question as i have very limited javascript skills. All i want to do is modify a variable in a function then return the new variable value ready for use in the funcion again.

An example of this is with a simple button that each time when clicked will deduct ten points from the variable. like a gradual countdown with each click. The problem is that the variable is not updated each time it is returned.

Maybe my starting approach to javascript is way out, thats why i dont seem to be able to find out much about this. here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/*starting bank account*/
var bank = "200";
/* i want this function to deduct ten from the starting bank account and update the bank variable */
function Bank(bank) {
    var printout = document.getElementById("display_bank_result_here");
    bank = bank - 10;
    printout.innerHTML = bank;
    return bank;
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="Bank(bank)">remove 10 from bank</button>
<p id='display_bank_result_here'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

A pre-emptive thanks to everyone out there. i hope one day i will have enough skills to return the favour to someone else in my posistion.

Robert

Comment: First issue is that you're setting bank as a string variable, it should be `var bank = 200;`, **edit**,but as others have already answered, you don't need to pass it via the function parameter, as it's already got "global scope"

Comment: You're welcome, but remember to give [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to those who have helped by submitting answers

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by scope.
Scope defines where variables and methods are defined/situated.

Everyting inside a function is inside the scope of that particular function.
Your function `Bank` also defines that same variable bank.
This overrides the variable bank you defined at the top of the script for that function.

There are two options: you could completly remove the bank variable of the function or change its name. For what you are using, I would just remove it.

change your `Bank` function to this

```
function Bank ()
{
    var printout=document.getElementById("display_bank_result_here");
    bank=bank-10;
    printout.innerHTML =bank;
    // You don't need to return it as it is changed inside the function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `bank`.

In the function `Bank` the `bank` variable is referring to the local one, not the global one. That shouldn't be a problem, as soon as you use the `return` value of the function to update your global variable:

```
<button onclick="bank = Bank(bank)">remove 10 from bank</button>
```

Of course, you could also solve it avoid the shadowing, for example:

```
function Bank () {
    var printout=document.getElementById("display_bank_result_here");
    bank -= 10;

    printout.innerHTML =bank;
}
```

Then the `return` is not needed.

Also, you could avoid the global variable at all, put in the `printout` the starting value:

```
<button onclick="decreaseBank()">remove 10 from bank</button>
<p id='display_bank_result_here'>200</p>
```

And your JS will be something like:

```
function decreaseBank () {
    var printout = document.getElementById("display_bank_result_here");

    // with subtraction the value of `innerHTML` will be converted in Number
    // automatically.
    var bank = printout.innerHTML - 10;

    printout.innerHTML = bank;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey i really like the second way of doing this, it seems easier to me, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is unneccesary to pass the parameter bank in the function. Just do this:

```
function Bank() {
    var printout = document.getElementById("display_bank_result_here");
    bank = bank - 10;
    printout.innerHTML = bank;
}
```

If you name the local variable (your parameter) bank, then it hides the global variable bank. The statement bank = bank - 10; will only be applied to the local variable not the global one.